# What metasyntax notation is Python using?

Tags: python, parsing, interpreter

Full grammar specification for Python 3.6.3 is as follows: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

It looks like EBNF appended by some special constructs taken from regular expressions, for example: `()*` (repeat zero or more times?) and `()+` (repeat one or more times?).

What metasyntax is Python using and where its specification can be found?

#### Update

Python's grammar is defined in this [file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Grammar/Grammar) (thanks @larsks). However, the question still stands - what notation is used?

Comment: It doesn't use that grammar to generate its parser. The actuall grammar is in ASDL format in [Python.asdl](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/Python.asdl)

Comment: So why is it even there? I assumed if it's not what is actually used by CPython it's at least equivalent.

Comment: @kindall: That's the definition of the AST structure, not the grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python grammar is parsed by the parser in the [Parser](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Parser) directory of the source.  You can see this in [Makefile.pre](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Makefile.pre.in#L779).  This generates `Include/graminit.[ch]`, which are used in, e.g., `Python/ast.c` as well as `Modules/parsermodule.c`.

The format of the grammar is described at the [bottom of pgen.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/pgen.c#L701):

> Input is a grammar in extended BNF (using * for repetition, + for
>   at-least-once repetition, [] for optional parts, | for alternatives and
>   () for grouping).

Comment: Thanks for the info on the source file, that's very useful. However, we still don't know what notation is used  exactly.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the comments from parser, which hopefully answer that question.

Comment: @siegmeyer: it's an idiosyncratic and loosely documented format without a formal specification, created specifically for parsing python by the python development team. The only unambiguous and definitive description is the pgen program which interprets it and creates the cpython parser.

Comment: I was trying to avoid saying "the notation used is the notation supported by pgen", but @rici said it :).  Thanks!